# Permutation in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

By book states the following:

> "Given the permutation $( 1 , 2)$ in $S_n$, what elements commute with
>   it ? Certainly any permutation leaving both $1$ and $2$ fixed does.
>   There are $(n - 2) !$ such. Also $( 1 , 2)$ commutes with itself. This
>   way we get $2 (n - 2) !$ elements in the group generated by $( 1 , 2)$
>   and the $(n- 2) !$ permutations leaving $1$ and $2$ fixed. Are there
>   others? There are $n(n - 1 ) /2$ transpositions and these are
>   precisely all the conjugates of $( 1 , 2).$ Thus the conjugate class
>   of $( 1 , 2)$ has in it $n(n - 1 ) /2$ elements."

How did they get those results?

Comment: I count 7 results in that paragraph --- which ones do you need help with? And what's $l$? is that a typo for $1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson That was a typo, I did mean $1$. And I need help with all $7$ if you don't mind.

Comment: So, you don't see why any permutation leaving both 1 and 2 fixed commutes with $(1,2)$? Do you know what $(1,2)$ means? and what a permutation is? and what "commutes" means?

Comment: This is an excerpt from Dummit and Foote... The only logical step is that the size of the conjugacy class is the index of the centralizer, i.e. $|S_{n} :\; C_{S_{n}}((12))|$ = size of conjugacy class. Hence, $|C_{S_{n}}((12))| = \frac{n!}{\frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{2}} = 2\cdot (n-2)!$.

Comment: @ChrisK That is right, my book caps it off with that result at the end but I first need help how they got these results first.

Comment: @user104235, in keeping with the fact that my comment is looking a bit like a solution, I have posted it down below. Which results are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Chris, I hope you have more luck getting that information than I have had so far.

Comment: @ChrisK In the second sentence, how did they get $(n-2)!$ such ways?

Comment: @user104235, suppose 1 and 2 are fixed... so 1 -> 1 and 2 -> 2. Then 3 can map to any of the remaining $n-2$ elements. Then, we can map 4 to any of the remaining $n-3$ elements. Hence, the number of combinations is $1\cdot 1\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-3)\cdot ... \cdot 2\cdot 1 = (n-2)!$.

Comment: @ChrisK Thank you very much! I see it now. And how about $2(n-2)!$? In the third sentence?

Comment: @user104235, Any of the $(n-2)!$ cycles commutes with $(12)$, since $(12)$ is disjoint. Let $\sigma$ be one of these cycles. Then, $(12)((12)\sigma) = \sigma = (\sigma(12))(12) = ((12)\sigma)(12)$ and so $(12)\sigma$ also commutes with $(12)$. Since $(12)\sigma$ and $\sigma$ are unique, there are at least $2\cdot (n-2)!$ elements that commute with $(12)$.

Comment: @ChrisK Thank you, Chris!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excerpt from Dummit and Foote... The only logical step is that the size of the conjugacy class is the index of the centralizer, i.e. $|S_{n} :\; C_{S_{n}}((12))|$ = size of conjugacy class. Hence, $|C_{S_{n}}((12))| = \frac{n!}{\frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{2}} = 2\cdot (n-2)!$. Hence, we conclude that there are no other elements of $S_{n}$ that commute with $(12)$.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is the following :

If $\sigma = (1 2)$, then for any $\tau \in S_n$,
$$
\eta := \tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = (\tau(1) \tau(2))
$$
In particular, $\eta$ is also a a transposition. Furthermore, if $\eta$ is *any* transposition, then there is a $\tau \in S_n$ such that $\eta = \tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$. Hence, the conjugacy class of $\sigma$ consists of all the transpositions in $S_n$.

Count the number of transpositions in $S_n$. This is the cardinality of $C(\sigma)$, the conjugacy class of $\sigma$.

By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, the centralizer $Z(\sigma)$ and $C(\sigma)$ are related by the equation
$$
|Z(\sigma)|C(\sigma)| = |S_n| = n!
$$
Hence,
$$
|Z(\sigma)| = \frac{n!}{|C(\sigma)|}
$$

Comment: How can I apply your answer to show that, for example, there are $n(n - 1 ) /2$ transpositions? Or there are $2 (n - 2) !
$ elements in the third sentence?

Comment: A transposition is just a choice of 2 numbers out of $n$ - so, you get ${n\choose 2}$ transpositions.